# How do I get a list of all deployments for a resource group (including those that may have had the same name)?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

Within Azure's portal, The deployments page for a resource group lists deployments with a unique name. If a deployment is created with the same name, it appears to overwrite the previous deployment, to the extent the previous deployment is no longer visible within the deployment list. There appears to be no filters or groupings that can be unset to allow viewing a list of all deployments that have occurred.

How can I view a list of all deployments within a resource group, independent of their name?

Comment: Not sure why everyone is saying they're not available. The "Activity Log" page probably has what you're looking for: https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_ActivityLog/ActivityLogBlade/queryInputs~/%7B%22user%22%3A%22%40me%22%7D

Answer (score 2):

Azure deployment are identified with names.
Once you update the deployment with the same name previous once cannot be seen anymore.
If you need to see the status after deployment you should consider giving them different names.

However there are only 800 deployment with different names are supported by Azure Resource Manager for a particular Resource Group, you should consider this fact too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check all the deployments with the same names, the previous ones will always be overwritten, your option is to use the different deployment names to deploy the templates in the resource group.

For example, you could use the powershell [`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-2.8.0) to deploy the template, just specify the `-Name` parameter with different values, it is the name of the deployment.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "testdep" -ResourceGroupName "joytest" -TemplateFile C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\temp1.json -TemplateParameterFile C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\para1.json
```

Then in the resource group -> `Deployments` in the portal, you will find all of them.